# Why was the helicopter searching for survivors?

Tags: plot-explanation, leviathan

Near the end of Leviathan (1989), the final three survivors of a doomed underwater silver mining station are dismayed to discover that the company that employs them has declared them already dead and therefore will not be sending the promised ship to pick them up.

They escape to the surface in their diving suits and are almost immediately spotted by a coast guard helicopter that had been searching for people in the water.

Why was the helicopter there? Was it looking for them? If so, who told it to do so?

Comment: Just because the company called it off doesn't necessarily mean the Coast Guard/government had as well.. *shrug*